# Change Back color of Windows Form using Another Form Application

Tags: winforms, ipc

I have 2 windows form applications.

From Main application, on button clicked, I want to change form color of target application.

Comment: Please read [ask]

Comment: `I want...` is not a question and shows zero research

Answer (score 0):

You must pass Form1 to the second form, then on the second form you can do something like this

```
Form1.BackColor = Color.Green;
```

Did not check if that is the correct syntax as i answered this on my phone.

Comment: How can I pass the form? Because these are 2 separate c# applications. Thanks for reply.

Comment: My bad, did not know these were two Different applications. Have a look at the winapi, I think this might do the job:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162964(v=vs.85).aspx